# log4j2 can't write exception trace in log file

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to print the stack trace of an exception in the log file but to no avail. The configuration file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout>
                <alwaysWriteExceptions>false</alwaysWriteExceptions>
                <pattern>%d{dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n %ex</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

%ex is ignored

This is code that generate error.

```
    public void getSingle(){
        try{
            //cut
        }catch (Exception e){
            //program enter in this exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            UtilsService.openAlertDialog(resources.getString("title.error"),null,UtilsService.getExceptionMessage(e),Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            logger.error("Class exception: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
logger.error("Class exception: " + e);
```

You are constructing just one string that gets printed. The `toString` of Exception is inherited from `Throwable` where it prints the Exception class name and the message. This gets added to the string "Class exception: " to form one string that is getting printed.

You want to pass the exception to the `logger.error` as an argument

```
logger.error("Class exception: " + e, e);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine.